# Sore on Yorkshire Terrier external mouth / chin. Visit to vet required?

Tags: dogs, health

I'm taking care of a Yorkshire terrier for a friend. She's quite a shy and nervous dog but has warmed up over the last few days and is always requesting affection and even sleeps on our bed. However, this morning after her walk we noted some blood on her chin. At first I thought it was just a graze from an injury sustained in her walk, but now I'm not so sure as a couple of hours later it still looks very sore. I've attached some images. Is this something I should let a vet handle or will it clear up on it's own? Pics attached

Other than that she seems to be behaving normally. Hungry, usual patterns of behaviour, etc.

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

Comment: I know this may sound a bit nasty, but have you found out if she reacts in any way upon physical contact with the wound/bruise/whatever?

Comment: Useful general principle: if you are asking whether you should visit the vet, you probably should visit the vet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very difficult to see well because of inadequate light and her fur. From what I can see, it looks like "road rash" --a scrape to her chin.
First thing is trim the hair around the wound--it will grow back. Then clean the area with a gauze pad and warm water. Check the area for swelling , pus, signs of infection.

Next, light from the bottom and take a new pic and post it. Then, with a new gauze pad, apply betadine, povodine/iodine antiseptic. Check and clean the wound area several times a day--especially after meals. If the wound appears to be healing and she eating well with no behavior changes, you can probably avoid a vet  visit. If there are any signs of infection, she may ultimately need antibiotics. Please check back in and let us know!

Comment: Hi M.Mat, thanks for your answer. Although this was several months back now, your answer is closest to the advice we ended up following at the time. Last time we saw her, she was all healed up and in fine form!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that she had an injury during the walk, or were you just guessing that might be the case?

If you're sure it's a small *injury*, I would check to make sure none of her teeth or gums are sore. If not, I think you can just observe for a few days to make sure it's healing about as quickly as you would expect a similar wound on your own body. If the teeth or gums are sore, or the wound doesn't heal quickly, definitely see the vet.

If you're not sure what this is, and you can reach the owner, ask them if they've seen the problem before. For all I can tell from the photo, this might be an allergic reaction that the dog is scratching. The owner may be able to tell you how to treat it.

Otherwise, I would take the dog to the vet on the next day they're open.